# UITableViewHeaderFooterView* header =[self.tableView headerViewForSection:0];

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have the following header of a tableview:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView* header =[self.tableView headerViewForSection:0];
```

This header has an imageview which I added programatically as a subview. How can I modify and reload this image or anything in header, without having to do a [tableView reloadData]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think u can enumerate on the subviews of header like this:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView* header =[self.tableView headerViewForSection:0];
for(UIView *v in header.subviews){
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
         {
           UIImageView *imgView = (UImageView*)v;
           //do ur stuff here for modification
            break;
         }   
    }
```

if u have multiple ImageViews u can differ between them with **tag**

Comment: Ok let me try it and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I'm getting the following error on this line: UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView)v; It says Used type 'UIIMageView' where arithmetic or pointer type required...

Comment: Ah sorry, cast it as a pointer:
`UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)v;`

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example? thank you! [Edit] just saw your example thanks

Comment: `UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)v;`

Comment: Thank you. I guess now I need to figure out why header =[self.tableView headerViewForSection:0]; is coming out nil..

Comment: Are u sure u pass a correct view for header in this method:
`- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Answer (score 0):

you can set an IBOUTLET property for the view you would like to access.

Comment: I'm not using interface builder.